# How to use groupby in dataframe and still show all the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Have a dataframe with 15 columns, and am trying to use groupby to find the maximum value of one of those columns.

This shows what I've been doing and the output. I am getting the maximum value of `item_number_revision` in each `item_number_start` I would like to also be able to show all of my other existing columns in the original dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Python doesn't _have_ dataframes. When asking questions about pandas, please always include the [tag:pandas] tag, as iIt introduces new data types and idioms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `item_number_revision` to contain max by group, you can do this:

```py
data1 = df.set_index('item_number_start').assign(item_number_revision=df.groupby('item_number_start')['item_number_revision'].max()).reset_index()
```

Input:

```
   item_number_start  item_number_revision other_column
0            80-0010                     1            a
1            80-0011                     2            b
2            80-0012                     3            c
3            80-0010                     4            d
4            80-0011                     5            e
5            80-0012                     6            f
6            80-0010                     7            g
7            80-0011                     8            h
8            80-0012                     9            i
9            80-0010                    10            j
10           80-0011                    11            k
11           80-0012                    12            l
```

Output:

```
   item_number_start  item_number_revision other_column
0            80-0010                    10            a
1            80-0011                    11            b
2            80-0012                    12            c
3            80-0010                    10            d
4            80-0011                    11            e
5            80-0012                    12            f
6            80-0010                    10            g
7            80-0011                    11            h
8            80-0012                    12            i
9            80-0010                    10            j
10           80-0011                    11            k
```

Alternatively, if you want to preserve the original column and add a new column containing the max, you can do this:

```py
data1 = df.set_index('item_number_start').assign(item_number_revision_max=df.groupby('item_number_start')['item_number_revision'].max()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   item_number_start  item_number_revision other_column  item_number_revision_max
0            80-0010                     1            a                        10
1            80-0011                     2            b                        11
2            80-0012                     3            c                        12
3            80-0010                     4            d                        10
4            80-0011                     5            e                        11
5            80-0012                     6            f                        12
6            80-0010                     7            g                        10
7            80-0011                     8            h                        11
8            80-0012                     9            i                        12
9            80-0010                    10            j                        10
10           80-0011                    11            k                        11
11           80-0012                    12            l                        12
```

In the examples above, we use `set_index()` to temporarily make the original DataFrame use an index that matches that of the `groupby()...max()`  Series, then we use `assign()` to either overwrite the column we took the max of, or add a new column, where each row is assigned the max for its group. In the end, we use `reset_index()` to restore the column we temporarily set as the index.

**UPDATE**:

To delete all rows except those with item_number_revision equal to item_number_revision_max, we can do this:

```py
data1 = (
    df.join(
        df.groupby('item_number_start')['item_number_revision'].max()
            .to_frame().set_index('item_number_revision', append=True), 
        on=['item_number_start', 'item_number_revision'], how='right')
    )
```

Output:

```
   item_number_start  item_number_revision other_column
9            80-0010                    10            j
10           80-0011                    11            k
11           80-0012                    12            l
```

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot! How could I delete the rows where item_number_revision doesn't equal item_number_revision_max?

Comment: Please see my updated answer showing how to delete all rows except those with item_number_revision equal to the max for the group.

Comment: Do you need more help with this?